# Make only selected and grouped items movable with the mouse

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I want to make only two items movable with the mouse. These two items should be grouped so that you can move them together across the window.

```py
 canvas.create_line(500, 420, 500, 380, fill="lightgreen", width=5)
    canvas.create_line(520, 400, 480, 400, fill="lightgreen", width=5)

    def on_click(event):
        selected = canvas.find_overlapping(event.x - 10, event.y - 10, event.x + 10, event.y + 10)
        if selected:
            canvas.selected = selected[-1]  # select the top-most item
            canvas.startxy = (event.x, event.y)
            print(canvas.selected, canvas.startxy)
        else:
            canvas.selected = None

    def on_drag(event):
        if canvas.selected:
            # calculate distance moved from last position
            dx, dy = event.x - canvas.startxy[0], event.y - canvas.startxy[1]
            # move the selected item
            canvas.move(canvas.selected, dx, dy)
            # update last position
            canvas.startxy = (event.x, event.y)

    canvas.bind("<Button-1>", on_click)
    canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", on_drag)
```

Comment: It is better to use frame.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.